# Using JavaScript with UIWebView- Swift 3.0

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to display a website. When the user presses a button, a `struct` is created that takes the URL, the title, and the image.

For the title, I use `let titleFromJS = mainWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector(\".c-page-title\").textContent;")!`

But, for the image, it's harder. The image link is wrapped in a `<source srcset>` and that is wrapped in a `<picture>` container. I want to locate it by class id which is `c-picture` but I do not know how to get the content of the source container.

Could anyone help me? Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks so much in advance!

Cheers,
Theo
[image: source]

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid force-unwrapping your result from your first JS statement, otherwise your app will crash should that element not exist. A guard statement that returns if the result from `mainWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` is `nil` might be a better alternative.

```
guard let titleFromJS = mainWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.querySelector(\".c-page-title\").textContent;") else {
    return
}
```

To access the source of the picture, you can get it from the the `img` element inside the `picture` element: `document.querySelector('.c-picture > img')]0].currentSrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but your answer didn't seem to work. I attached an image of the html source code when i inspect the element. Does that help?

Comment: Let me know if it works now. I changed `#c-picture` to `.c-picture`.